# Retrieving nested details from info stored in a database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I have a list of movies stored with a database and when I make a request to the endpoint the data is returned as such

```
 **{
        "Actors": [],
        "_id": "613345b5c3e971923de94876",
        "Title": "Gladiator",
        "Description": "A former Roman General sets out to exact vengeance against the corrupt emperor who murdered his family and sent him into slavery.",
        "ImagePath": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51m50jXZsUL._AC_.jpg",
        "Featured": true,
        "Genre": [
            {
                "_id": "61373bf26af4f5693de54a3e",
                "Name": "Action",
                "Description": "Action films involve one or more heroes thrust into a series of challenges requiring physical feats, extended fights, extensive stunts and frenetic chases.Story and character development are generally secondary to explosions, fist fights, gunplay and car chases. Both historically and currently, action films have wide commercial appeal and enjoy box office success. The action film revolves around a narrative, to be sure, but more importantly than that, a hero; when a moviegoer thinks of an action picture, more often than not they are thinking of a specific actor and the obstacles their character(s) must overcome."
            }
        ],
        "Director": [
            {
                "_id": "613741376af4f5693de54a41",
                "Name": "Ridley Scott",
                "Bio": "Ridley Scott is an English film producer and director, regarded as one of the biggest names in Hollywood. Ridley is known for his science-fiction horror films, such as the cult classic ‘Alien’ and the science-fiction existential drama ‘Blade Runner.’ Belonging to an army family, Scott was in love with films since childhood. He began his career with short films and eventually made his first feature film, ‘The Duellists,’ in 1977. The film won the ‘Best Debut Film’ honor at the ‘Cannes Film Festival.’ However, it was his second feature film ‘Alien’ that introduced him to Hollywood in a grand style. His highly moody and atmospheric style of directing was fairly new to mainstream Hollywood audiences. Scott quickly sealed his place as one of the most prominent young directors. Scott repeated his mainstream success with ‘Blade Runner.’ Over the years, with the success of films such as ‘Kingdom of Heaven,’ ‘Robin Hood,’ and ‘Black Hawk Down,’ he became a name to reckon with. Of late, he has garnered appreciation for films such as ‘Gladiator,’ ‘The Martian,’ ‘Prometheus,’ and ‘Alien: Covenant.’ He has earned multiple nominations for prestigious awards such as the ‘Emmy Award,’ the ‘Academy Award,’ and the ‘Golden Globe Award.’ He has won two ‘Emmies’ too",
                "Birth": "1937",
                "Death": ""
            }
        ]
    }**
```

When I try to retrieve this information in another view

```
**<div className = "movie-director">
            <span className = "label">Director: </span>
            <span className = "value">{movie.Director.Name}</span>**
```

All I get is the ID of the director.  I have tried to access the array using Array[].name but can't seem to get anything to display.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to access a property of an array, not the property on the first item in the array. Try calling `movie.Director[0].Name` or looping over the `movie.Director` array to get all of the names.

Comment: For some reason I was trying exactly that yesterday and didn't work.  Seems to be working now though - thanks